# Is it possible to use a worker app with express on heroku?

Tags: heroku, discord.js

I'm trying to port one of my bots to heroku on a worker app, everything works correctly, but I want to use express on it too. My question is, is it possible to use express on a worker app? If so, how would I do this? If not, would there be an alternative to this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use an express server as normal. When you put your app on heroku, it should be given a URL - use that URL for any actions on the express server.

For tutorials on `express`, see https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html (official docs)

Comment: I tried to and ended up with "No web processes running"